# Click on map close all markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have this code that if the user clicks any part of the map all infowindows should close. But I have no idea why it's not working.

How I open my infowindow:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

What I have to close all upon map click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.close(map, marker);
    });
```

EDIT: Having a hard time finding a solution. Most threads that show are about close icon if one is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one marker on your map, named "marker", this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.close();
});
```

As long as the function is run where both the "map" variable and the "infowindow" variable are in scope.